# Can I use hyperparameters obtained from tuning in R in the final model training in python?

Tags: hyperparameter-tuning

I am currently creating and evaluating several models for a dataset.

Because I am more versed in R and like the `tidymodel` workflow, I am using `tidymodels` and `tune` to find the optimal hyperparameters for e.g. a `lightgbm` model.

However because the dataset is very large and R not as performant as python, I do this using a sample of the full data.

Once I've obtained the optimal parameters, could I use those to train the final model on the full data in python?

I don't see a reason why not but I am not sure I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the model being retrained in Python uses different data, then the "optimal" hyperparameters may be different. All hyperparameters may not be invariant to size of data. The larger data may contain more noise/signal or different noise/signal.

My guess - if your sample is a random sample from the larger data and you have trained multiple samples and the hyperparameters are consistent, then you are probably close.

Also, depending on your use case, "optimal" may really mean good enough. The business decisions that are derived from the predictions may not improve with a slightly "better" model. You can use the sampled hyperparameters, train with the full data, examine the decisions that are being made from the predictions, and go from there.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. Optimal is as you say a judgement call as well and most parameters converge very closely in the top models. Additionally always looking at the final result to say "it worked/did not work" makes sense.